# How to Convert Number into Signs (Math) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, random, converters

I am trying to make Math Quiz that asking with two random numbers (1, 10) with randomly choice with sum, difference or product. I used `z = random.randint(1, 3)` to generate sum, difference or product, but I want to use this numbers  converting to signs like "x", "/", or "+" to shown output to ask Question because I am new to Python language and I am trying to learn on how to convert numbers to symbols.

**My Code Here:**

```
import random

def askNum():
  while(1):
    try:
      userInput = int(input("Enter a number: "))
      break
    except ValueError:
      print("Incorrect Input!")

  return userInput

def askQuestion():
  x = random.randint(1, 10)
  y = random.randint(1, 10)
  z = random.randint(1, 3)

  print(" 1 = product \n 2 = sum \n 3 = difference")
  print("What is " + str(x)+" " + str(z)+" " + str(y)+"?")

  u = askNum()
  if z == 1 and u==x*y:
    return 1  #product
  elif z == 2 and u==x+y:
    return 1 #sum
  elif z == 3 and u==x/y:
    return 1 #difference
  else:
    return 0
amount = 10
correct = 0
for i in range(amount):
  correct += askQuestion()

print("You got %d correct out of %d" % (correct, amount))
```

**Reality Output:**

```
dm15125@isu:/u1/work/Python/math> python3 mathquiz.py
 1 = product
 2 = sum
 3 = difference
What is 4 2 6?
Enter a number: 10
 1 = product
 2 = sum
 3 = difference
What is 7 2 6?
Enter a number: 13
 1 = product
 2 = sum
 3 = difference
What is 3 2 3?
Enter a number: 6
 1 = product
 2 = sum
 3 = difference
What is 8 3 4?
Enter a number: 2
 1 = product
 2 = sum
 3 = difference
What is 8 3 10?
Enter a number: 0.8
Incorrect Input!
Enter a number: .8
Incorrect Input!
Enter a number: 0
 1 = product
 2 = sum
 3 = difference
What is 2 2 6?
Enter a number: 8
 1 = product
 2 = sum
 3 = difference
What is 6 3 4?
Enter a number: 1.5
Incorrect Input!
Enter a number: 2
 1 = product
 2 = sum
 3 = difference
What is 7 1 10?
Enter a number: 70
 1 = product
 2 = sum
 3 = difference
What is 9 2 5?
Enter a number: 14
 1 = product
 2 = sum
 3 = difference
What is 5 1 10?
Enter a number: 50
You got 8 correct out of 10
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
dm15125@isu:/u1/work/Python/math> python3 mathquiz.py
What is 4 + 6?
Enter a number: 10
What is 7 + 6?
Enter a number: 13
What is 3 + 3?
Enter a number: 6
What is 8 / 4?
Enter a number: 2
What is 8 / 10?
Enter a number: 0.8
Incorrect Input!
Enter a number: .8
Incorrect Input!
Enter a number: 0
What is 2 + 6?
Enter a number: 8
What is 6 / 4?
Enter a number: 1.5
Incorrect Input!
Enter a number: 2
What is 7 * 10?
Enter a number: 70
What is 9 + 5?
Enter a number: 14
What is 5 * 10?
Enter a number: 50
You got 8 correct out of 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```
print(" 1 = product \n 2 = sum \n 3 = difference")
print("What is " + str(x)+" " + str(z)+" " + str(y)+"?")
```

instead of `str(z)`, define a list like `ops = ['*', '+', '-']` and use `ops[z - 1]`. The `- 1` is because your `z` starts from 1, but array index starts from zero.
So your function would become:

```
def askQuestion():
    ops = ['*', '+', '-']
    x = random.randint(1, 10)
    y = random.randint(1, 10)
    z = random.randint(1, 3)

    print(" 1 = product \n 2 = sum \n 3 = difference")
    print("What is " + str(x) + " " + ops[z - 1] + " " + str(y) + "?")

    u = askNum()
    if z == 1 and u==x*y:
        return 1  #product
    elif z == 2 and u==x+y:
        return 1 #sum
    elif z == 3 and u==x/y:
        return 1 #difference
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary to do this:

```
operators = {
   1: "+",
   2: "-",
   3: "/",
   4: "*"
}
operators = operator[z] // where z is the random integer for gettig the operator.
```

The in your print statement

```
print("What is " + str(x)+" " + str(operator)+" " + str(y)+"?")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an "if" sentence within your askQuestion function to choose what symbol to print out.

Or maybe use a list like this one:

> symbols_list = ['*','+','-']
>
> symbols_list[z-1]

And then use "z" value to index it (remember that the first position is indexed with 0 not 1).

Or use a dictionary with "z" as the key to retrieve the adequate symbol:

> symbols_dict = {1:'*', 2:'+',3:'-'}
>
> symbols_dict[z]

As you can see there are many options, just choose the one you like more.